# qemu-img info: disk size vs virtual size - misunderstanding

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

please note following log:

```
[user@machine]$ qemu-img info kvm_1
image: kvm_1
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 146G (157286400000 bytes)
disk size: 101G
cluster_size: 65536
backing file: /xyz.qcow2
backing file format: qcow2
Format specific information:
    compat: 0.10


[user@machine]$ qemu-img info kvm_2
image: kvm_2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 146G (157286400000 bytes)
disk size: 146G
cluster_size: 65536
backing file: /xyz.qcow2
backing file format: qcow2
Format specific information:
    compat: 0.10
```

The second machine (`kvm_2`) was fallocated using `fallocate` tool. 
Can anyone explain a difference? What are difference in performance between these two config?
Does it matter for `qcow2` format? What about `raw` format? What is root cause of difference in performance (unless any exists)?